# UICollectionView: Customize UICollectionViewFlowLayout headers (multiple headers and header position)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, uicollectionview

I would like to convert my current table view based data grids to the new `UICollectionView` classes.

This is how my current grids look like:

[image: My current table view based data grid]

My grid has two headers:

- year (2006a, 2007a, etc) and
- type ("Revenue", "EBITDA", etc).

From Apple's documentation I understand that I would need to **subclass FlowLayout** to get two headers ([Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html)) and, in particular, override `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath:` to support new supplementary views (headers).

However, I did not find any sample or tutorial on how to do this. As I am stuck here, I would appreciate if you could point me to the right direction in coding this correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810628/uicollectionview-decoration-view/12824761#12824761) an how to support decoration views. It would be similar for supplementary views, with the following differences:

- Instead of registering the NIB or class on the layout you would call `– registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:` on the UICollectionView instance
- In your view controller for the UICollectionView you would implement `– collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` similar to the method for normal cells
- In the layout subclass you need to implement the following method `– layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath:` to position the supplementary views at their positions
- In the `– layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` make sure to add all the supplementary views you want (similar to the decoration view in the example I posted)

I don't have access to my example code right now, but I will post it later.