# how to get the instance of the decoration view in the collection view?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I've implemented an UICollectionView with a custom layout. I know how to present visual adornments for the entire collection view, but don't know how to present different image  for every section. I need to get the instance of decoration view by indexPath. I found this on Apple Document:

Use this method to create a layout attributes object for a decoration view in the collection view. Decoration views are a type of supplementary view but do not present data that is managed by the collection view’s data source. Instead, they mostly present visual adornments for a section or for the entire collection view.

**It is up to you to decide how to use the indexPath parameter to identify a given decoration view. Typically, you use the decorationViewKind parameter to identify the type of the decoration view and the indexPath information to distinguish between different instances of that view.**

who can tell me how to do it in detail?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Please include the code where you currently load the content for each collection view cell.

Comment: There's a great tutorial that covers this ... it's a little dated but still very relevant. Look at http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Comment: Thanks man!I just follow the tutorial online: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810628/uicollectionview-decoration-view). actually, all the solutions are same.@BrianShamblen

Comment: Thanks man! I downloaded the source code in the link that you show to me! and read it carefully! but i still can't find the way to solve my problem. I want to get the decoration view's instance and set different background image for each section's decoration view. @MDB983

Comment: in your custom Layout you can respond to:  (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:(NSString*)decorationViewKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath or - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                                                     atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

 and set the background accordingly. The indexPath contains the Section

Comment: thanks for your patience! but does there have any property named backgroud image or color in UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes class?@MDB983

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer my own question!
Thanks for [this article](http://www.ericjchapman.com/jekyll/update/ios/2014/11/10/ios-changing-section-background-color-in-UICollectionView.html)!

First, subclass `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` and add any property you want.

Second, in the function `layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind(elementKind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes!`, set the property.

Third, in the `UICollectionReusableView` class, override the function `applyLayoutAttributes:` to get the custom `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` instance that contains your property.

Done!

Comment: @Pete Thanks man! I appreciate your help in correcting my spelling error!.

Comment: @vmeyer Thanks for the reminder. The author probably changed his blog's structure. I have fixed it.