# UICollectionViewCell inconsistent shadow with decoration view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, shadow, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using [IGListKit](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit) with my `UICollectionView`. For now the CollectionView is pretty simple, as it only have one cell per section. That cell contains an inner horizontal `UICollectionView` as an image slideshow.

As I need some shadowing around my entire sections, I am using [Decoration Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810628/uicollectionview-decoration-view), and apply it a border shadow: `layer.shadowPath`

I noticed something weird, the shadow's opacity changes upon the picture currently displayed in the slideshow. If the picture (or a portion of the picture) is bright, you can see the shadow opacity changing.

I don't know if it is something I can fix.

You can clearly see that if I take a screenshot while swiping pictures in the slideshow, the shadow on the top is darker on one side.

[image]

**Code for decoration view:**

```
class FeedItemBackgroundShadowView: UICollectionReusableView {

    // MARK: Initialization

    ... Constructors calling setup

    // MARK: Setup

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: Constants.cornerRadius).cgPath
    }

    func setup() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.5)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 12.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.35
}
```

Rest of the code a simply UICollectionViewCells that embed a UICollectionView

Comment: It might be about `override func layoutSubviews` method. Can you check when exactly that method is triggered as you scroll horizontally? The shadow behaviour might be strange until that method is triggered and actual bezierpath is added as a layer.

Comment: The `layoutSubviews` in the decoration cell (`FeedItemBackgroundShadowView`) is only called when I scroll vertically. It is not called when I swipe horizontally in the cells.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain it isn't an optical illusion?

[image]